# What effect does GPU temperature have on performance?

Tags: cooling

Under stress testing for extended period, it seems that high-end GPUs can approach 90 degrees centigrade.

Nvidia has confirmed, I believe, that its 980 series are "safe" to operate up to 92 degrees. But what effect does operating at these temperatures have on performance? Is it worth investing in additional cooling systems if your GPU is running at these temperatures?

Comment: Suggested migration to Superuser given the actual question here. You could instead ask for third party GPU cooler solutions on this SE.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia GPU's use something called "GPU Boost 2.0"
This software comes free of charge with your GPU, also no need to install GPU Boost!
What it does, is when your GPU has more thermal headroom (when it is cooler than it needs to be), it will overclock itself!
So when you run your GPU at a chilly 50 degrees, it will overclock itself.

You are also safe to operate your GPU at 90 degrees, there is only a small difference in life span when you use your GPU on high temps for extended periods of time, rather than keeping it cool and idle. :)

Conclusion: YES! lower temperatures do make a difference with your Nvidia GPU, because it will overclock itself when it has thermal headroom.
The GPU will be fine running 90 degrees for an extended period of time, it will just dislike you for it a little.

I hope i answered your question :)